# "Value cannot be null" when passing null arguments to SignalR client-side proxy

Tags: c#, json.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Using SignalR (v2.0.2) I'm getting this exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: o
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(Object value, String parameterName)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObjectInternal(Object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(Object o, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Hubs.HubProxy.Invoke[T](String method, Object[] args)
```

I'm calling the HubProxy with reflection, and I am passing in some null arguments that are triggering this error (aka, some items in the `Object[] args` are null). However, passing null for an argument to a method is a perfectly legitimate thing to do. Is this a bug in SignalR in that it is trying to serialize null parameters or is it a bug in Json.NET (v6.0.1) in that it shouldn't attempt to serialize a null object?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988724/null-value-exception-thrown-when-deserializing-null-value-json-net

Comment: @tweellt, I checked that link. It seems to be a similar error but not a similar situation.

Comment: Did you try another serialization? javascriptserializer?

Comment: @Dmitry, I have not attempted to replace the serialization in SignalR with any other framework. I really like Json.NET and don't want to replace it. I use it numerous other places in my software.

Comment: Show as your code! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug in SignalR that has been fixed and will be included in the upcoming 2.2.1 release. See their ticket [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1655).

Comment: As of October 2016 it appears that this is still an active argument. No fix is permanent yet.

Comment: Their latest release lists this as fixed: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.2.1.

Comment: Still happening in 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override `SignalR` hubs invocation method, for example:
customize `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute` like this:

```
public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
{

}
```

Then before invoke, you can check your request and make some processing if needed.

Comment: Please provide more details.