# SignalR gives and Error with Unity3D WebGL Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, signalr

I have got a SignalR connection working in the Unity3D Editor and Windows Standalone Build but when I do a WebGL build I get the following error when connecting to the Hub.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: format at System.String.FormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args)

I haven't been able to find an answer as to why this is happening only with WebGL and I am not even sure if it is because it is WebGL or because of something to do with Unity.

Has anyone else come across this and know why it is only being thrown on the WebGL build.

Edit: Adding trace of from the exception

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: format 
at System.String.FormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at System.String.Format (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.Object arg0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Resources.FormatNoConstructorMatch (System.Object p0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite (System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor descriptor, System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact (System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite (System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain callSiteChain) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor (System.Type serviceType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at System.Func`2[T,TResult].Invoke (T arg) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService (System.Type serviceType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService (System.Type serviceType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService (System.Type serviceType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T] (System.IServiceProvider provider) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnectionBuilder.Build () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at PlayerConnection..ctor (System.String hubUrl, System.String access_token) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at ConnectionManager.Init (System.String access_token) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at SetupManager+<ConnectToHubs>d__5.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutineManaged2 (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine (System.Collections.IEnumerator routine) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at SetupManager+<WaitForAccessToken>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutineManaged2(IEnumerator) UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator) <WaitForAccessToken>d__4:MoveNext() UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

I can debug both the hubUrl and access_token and print out in the debug their values so I know it isn't them causing it.

Comment: There is some wierdness with webgl builds certainly in 2019.1 atm, as I have logged and had confirmed a bug that if  you install HLAPI it wont compile ..it wouldnt surprise me to hear theres more

Comment: @BugFinder I saw that one too and had to remove the package, I am wondering if I should install an earlier version and test with that now.

Comment: it depends if you have something maybe generating a UUID from the HLAPI package and now its just returning null.

Comment: Installing the most recent LTS version 2017.4.26f1 atm, will test with it and update you/my question

Comment: 2017.4 was incompatible with SignalR so installed 2018.3.1 and it threw the same error so it isn't a Unity version issue.

Comment: have you managed to track what line throws the error

Comment: @BugFinder no not yet.

Comment: very odd, normally errors like that come with line numbers

Comment: @BugFinder due to how Unity does builds the line numbers don't represent anything from before the build, is tedious to say the least, have to go into `C:\Users\Username\AppData\LocalLow\CompanyName\AppName` just to find the debug for a standalone build lol

Comment: @BugFinder added the trace

Comment: which version of singalR is it?

Comment: @BugFinder SignalR version 2.4.1

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566453/value-cannot-be-null-when-passing-null-arguments-to-signalr-client-side-proxy which said it wasnt fixed in 2.4 ... so.. it still may not be fixed?

Comment: @BugFinder I did/ish (had a different issue with using SignalR with Unity3D that led me to avoid Newtonsoft other than as part of the SignalR plugins package), but it is failing before a json is even sent so don't see how that could be the issue.

Comment: Should add the only reason I have gone this route is that the method Unity provides is deprecated and they havn't released what they are going to do to replace it, so have gone this route of finding my own solution

Comment: by Plugins package I mean the DLLs and its dependancy DLLs which includes Newtonsoft which conflicts with the Unity Newtonsoft which in turn has platfrom dependant issues due to serialization which are corrected for in the Unity version of Newtonsoft which cant be used with SignalR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after much debugging and trying to figure this out it turns out to be an issue with threading (not that the exception indicates that).

Unity dosen't support multi-threading due to the lack of threading support in JavaScript, Essentially, anything in the `System.Threading` namespace is not supported but it is a requirement of SignalR.

Unity say they are planning to add multi-threading support but no time frame for when it will be added.

I will leave this here incase anyone else runs into this issue.